# check if a columns contains any str from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to use any() to check if the column contains any string from the list and make a new column with the corresponding results

```
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,1,3], 'animals': ['cat, frog', 'kitten, fish', 'frog2, fish']})
cats = ['kitten', 'cat']
df_data['cats'] = df_data.apply(lambda row: True if any(item in cats for item in row['animals']) else False, axis = 1)
```

I got these results, and I don't understand why it is False for the first two rows :

```
   A       animals   cats
0  2     cat, frog  False
1  1  kitten, fish  False
2  3   frog2, fish  False
```

I expect to get False for the last row only

Answer (score 1):

With pandas you should try your best not using for loop or apply , I am using `DataFrame` constructor with `isin` and `any`

```
df_data['cats']=pd.DataFrame(df_data.animals.str.split(', ').tolist()).isin(cats).any(1)
df_data
   A       animals   cats
0  2     cat, frog   True
1  1  kitten, fish   True
2  3   frog2, fish  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Flip your iterables

```
df_data['cats'] = df_data.apply(lambda row: True if any([item in row['animals'] for item in cats]) else False, axis = 1)

print(df_data)
#    A       animals   cats
# 0  2     cat, frog   True
# 1  1  kitten, fish   True
# 2  3   frog2, fish  False
```

If you look closely

```
item in row['animals'] for item in cats
```

will iterate over `cats` and see if the item is in `row['animals']`

```
item in cats for item in row['animals']
```

will iterate over `row['animals']` and see if the value of `row['animals']` is in the cats list

Comment: Just curious about whether you consider the speed of the code or not

Comment: In this case, I was worried about showing them the issue with their code. Sometimes I try to fix the mistakes, other times I try to inform of a better way. Though I do appreciate when I get to learn new things from your comments and answers. Also, I only really care about the speed of the code if the problem set is long enough to make speed an issue. Otherwise, readability is also good.

Comment: Ok that is fair enough :-)